# Dificultad al mostrar por pantalla un vector de productos y stock - C++

Tags: c++

como están?

Estoy trabado hace algunas horas para resolver el siguiente problema:

Ahora deberás calcular el precio de venta de varios productos.
Para esto, reemplazá el ingreso por consola del punto anterior por dos arreglos de cinco (5) decimales e inicializalos. Los arreglos tendrán el precio de compra y el stock de un producto en las mismas posiciones. Por ejemplo, en la posición 0 de los dos arreglos, estarán el precio y stock del primer producto. Por cada uno de estos valores, invocar la función “calcularPrecioDeVenta” en informar los precios de venta.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

int arregloderesultados[5];
int ganancia = arregloDePrecios[0,1,2,3,4]*20/100;
int arregloDePrecios[5] = {10, 25, 35, 45, 55};
int arregloDeStock[5] = {25, 50, 60, 10, 5};

using namespace std; 

int calcularPrecioDeVenta(int preciocompra, int stock)
{

if(stock >= 100 and preciocompra < 1500 ) {
ganancia = preciocompra * 15 / 100;
} else if (stock < 50) 
{
ganancia = preciocompra*15/100;
}
int iva = preciocompra*21/100;
return (preciocompra + ganancia + iva);

}

int main() {

cout << "A continuación se mostrará el precio y stock de cada producto: ";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

arregloderesultados[i] = calcularPrecioDeVenta(arregloDePrecios[i],arregloDeStock[i]);
cout << "El resultado es: " << arregloderesultados[i];
cin.get();

}

}
```

Me está dando dolores de cabeza como calcular la variable "ganancia" y además, de que lo otro no esté correctamente formulado.

Agradezco a quien me pueda dar una ayuda,
Gracias!

Comment: La variable global `ganancia`, ¿para qué se supone que sirve? No la usas en ningún sitio. ¿Y de dónde sale ese cálculo del 20% en la ganancia?

Answer (score 1):

> Me está dando dolores de cabeza como calcular la variable "ganancia" y

Y no me extraña, a mi además de dolor de cabeza me ha hecho un esguince en varias dendritas y he tenido un par de infartitos, tu declaración de la variable `ganancia` ni compila, ni tiene sentido:

```
// 'ganancia' hace referencia a 'arregloDePrecios' que está declarado después!
int ganancia = arregloDePrecios[0,1,2,3,4]*20/100;
int arregloDePrecios[5] = {10, 25, 35, 45, 55};
```

La declaración de la variable `ganancia` además de usar una variable que no existe (porque se declara después) aunque existiera la está usando mal.

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no es posible usar múltiples índices en una formación<sup>1</sup>:

```
int ganancia = arregloDePrecios[0,1,2,3,4]*20/100;
//                              ^^^^^^^^^ <--- Múltiples indices
```

Lo que sucede ahí es que estás usando el operador coma, cuyo funcionamiento es el siguiente:

1. Evalúa la expresión a la izquierda de la coma.
2. Descarta el resultado de la expresión.
3. Devuelve el resultado de la expresión a la derecha de la coma.

Así que tu múltiple indexación lo que hace es:

1. Evalúa `0`, lo descarta.
2. Evalúa `1,2,3,4`.

   1. Evalúa `1`, lo descarta.
   2. Evalúa `2,3,4`.

      1. Evalúa `2`, lo descarta.
      2. Evalúa `3,4`.

         1. Evalúa `3`, lo descarta.
         2. Evalúa `4`.
            Por lo que toda la expresión es equivalente a:

```
int ganancia = arregloDePrecios[4]*20/100;
```

Ahora que ha quedado claro tu disparate, si sigues el enunciado tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int main()
{
    int arregloDePrecios[5] = {10, 25, 35, 45, 55};
    int arregloDeStock[5] = {25, 50, 60, 10, 5};

    for (int indice = 0; indice != 5; ++indice)
        std::cout << "Precio de venta: " << calcularPrecioDeVenta(arregloDePrecios[indice], arregloDeStock[indice]) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*